# Ubuntu linux command extract substring inside

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I have a txt file on ubuntu containing

-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp              0 Feb 26 11:37 6.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp              0 Feb 26 11:37 7.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp              0 Feb 26 11:37 8.txt

can I just want to retrieve the file name like

6.txt 
7.txt 
8.txt

to another text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{print $NF}' your_file >only_names.txt
```

or

```
perl -lane '{print $F[scalar(@F)-1]}' your_file >only_names.txt
```

and if you want to change the existing file:

```
perl -i -lane '{print $F[scalar(@F)-1]}' your_file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cut -d' ' -f 9 f1.txt > f2.txt
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @slfan This command seems to work correctly. So it is an answer. Why you say that the command is not correct? I compared accepted answer (awk '{print $NF}' your_file) and my answer (cut -d' ' -f 9 f1.txt) and they give the same result

Answer (score 0):

If you file name are pretty uniform, I'd go with grep and a regular expression:

```
$ grep --color=never -oE '[[:alnum:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]{3}$' files.txt
```

The above disables color (which may interfere), only outputs the matching part (-o), uses extended regex (-E), and then finds one or more alpha-numeric characters, followed by a dot ("."), followed by exactly three alpha-numeric characters ([[:alnum:]]) and a line ending (the '$').

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains space, it could look like

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp 0 Feb 26 11:37 6.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp 0 Feb 26 11:37 7.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp 0 Feb 26 11:37 a filename with space
```

use this

`cut -d' ' -f9- f1.txt > f2.txt`